# General method for determining the sample size given the standard error

Tags: statistical-significance, sample-size, standard-error

What is the formula for calculating the minimum sample size needed to achieve a specified relative precision for a given sample statistic's standard error, at a specified level of significance?

Mostly I find formulas specific for the [sample](https://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/prc/section2/prc222.htm) [mean](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/429398/determining-sample-size-for-given-confidence-interval-and-margin-of-error). But I'm looking for the text-book description of the general case. Ideally this should already take into account the [case](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7004/calculating-required-sample-size-precision-of-variance-estimate) where the distribution of the sample statistic is unknown and one needs to find the standard error via bootstrapping.

### My approach

What I tried by reverse engineering is this relation for the standard error of a sample statistic $SE(\theta)$, the relative precision $\delta$ and significance level $\alpha$ $(\delta, \alpha \in [0,1])$.

$$
\begin{align}
SE(\theta) \overset{!}{≥} \frac{\delta \cdot \theta}{z(\alpha)} \, , \label{eq:one}\tag{1}
\end{align}
$$
with the critical value $z$ of a [one-/two-tailed hypotheses test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-_and_two-tailed_tests) for a given probability distribution. Since in general $\text{SE}(\theta) \sim \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$, one can solve (1) for $n$ to compute the appropriate sample size

#### Example

This [article](https://web.eecs.umich.edu/%7Efessler/papers/files/tr/stderr.pdf) summarizes the formulas for $SE(\theta)$ of sample mean $\bar{X}$, sample variance $S^2$ and standard deviation $S$ in the case of a normally distributed data set:
$$
\begin{align*}
    \sigma_{\bar{X}} &= \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}} \label{eq:two} \tag{2} \\
    \sigma_{S^2} &= \sigma^2\sqrt{\frac{2}{n-1}} \label{eq:three} \tag{3} \\
    \sigma_{S} &\approx \frac{1}{\sqrt{2(n-1)}} \quad \text{(for n > 10) } \, .\label{eq:four} \tag{4}
\end{align*}
$$

This leads to the minimum number of required samples $n$:
$$
\begin{align}
n_{\bar{X}} &= \left(\frac{\sigma}{\bar{X}} \cdot \frac{z_{1-\alpha/2}}{\delta}\right)^2 \label{eq:five} \tag{5}  \\
n_{S^2} &= 2\left(\frac{z_{1-\alpha/2}}{\delta}\right)^2 +1 \label{eq:six} \tag{6}  \\
n_{S} &= \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{z_{1-\alpha/2}}{\delta}\right)^2 +1 \label{eq:seven} \tag{7}
\end{align}
$$

The calculation implemented in Python:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats


def get_n(
    stat: str,
    alpha: float,
    delta: float,
    n_sides: int = 2,
    loc: float = 0.0,
    scale: float = 1.0,
) -> int:
    """
    Computes the required number of samples to draw from a normal distribution
    in order to estimate the mean, variance or standard deviation with
    specified precision and significance.

    Parameters
    ----------
    stat : str
        Specifies the statistic for which to compute the number of samples
    alpha : float
        Significance level used to compute the critical value of the
        tailed hypothesis test
    delta : float
        Required relative precision of the parameter estimation
    n_sides : int, optional
        Specifies wether a one- or two-tailed hypothesis is used to compute
        the critical value.
        Default is 2.
    loc: float, optional
        Position of the normal distribution. Default is 0.0
    scale: float, optional
        Width scale of the normal distribution. Default is 1.0

    Returns
    -------
    n : int
        Number of samples
    """

    # Critical value for tailed hypothesis test
    z: float = stats.norm.ppf(1 - alpha / n_sides)

    # Number of samples
    n: float
    if stat == "mean":
        n = ((scale * z) / (loc * delta)) ** 2
    elif stat == "var":
        n = 2 * (z / delta) ** 2 + 1
    elif stat == "std":
        n = 1.0 / 2 * (z / delta) ** 2 + 1
    else:
        raise ValueError(
            "Expected string from ['mean', 'var', 'std'] "
            f"for paramter 'stat', got '{stat}' ({type(stat).__name__})"
        )

    # Return integer
    return int(np.ceil(n))
```

For example, running this in the case of the sample mean, $\delta = 0.01$, $\alpha=0.05$ (two-tailed test) and normal distribution centered around 42 with width 2.3:

```py
loc = 42 # known population mean
scale = 2.3  # known population standard deviation
alpha = 0.05  # significance in %
delta = 0.01  # relative accuracy in %

stat = "mean"

n = get_n(
    stat=stat,
    alpha=alpha,
    delta=delta,
    loc=loc,
    scale=scale,
)
```

`--> n = 116`

A simple simulation to do the validation confirms it (using `np.random.normal(loc=loc, scale=scale, size=n)` and comparing the sample mean `np.mean()` to the population mean `loc`):
[image]
[image]